# Как реализовать скролл с плавной загрузкой контента в React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, прокрутка, content

Добрый день! 
Есть задача: на странице сайта, а именно в проектах стоит задача реализовать скрол с **плавной** загрузкой картинок и текста(всех проектов).
Как это реализовать?

Comment: Уточнение, использую библиотеку "react-scroll"

Comment: Гугл с запросом "images lazy load on scroll" вам в помощь

Comment: У вас не получается подгрузить картинки плавно? Или в принципе не получается загрузить?

Comment: Загрузить в принципе, они просто со старту рендерятся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При первой загрузке выполнить getContent():

```
function getContent() {
  apiMethod({ start: 0, count: 20 });
}
```

Component:

```
import React from 'react';

function onScrollList(event) {
  const scrollBottom = event.target.scrollTop + 
        event.target.offsetHeight == event.target.scrollHeight;

    if (scrollBottom) {
      loadContent(); //API method
    }
  }
}

function DataList() {
  return (
    <div onScroll={event => onScrollList(event)}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default DataList;
```

В API смотрите количество уже загруженных элементов, сравниваете с общим количеством элементов, если total > loaded, тогда делаете запрос:

```
function loadContent() {
  const total = 100;
  const data = []; // lenght == 40

  if(data.lenght < total) {
    apiMethod({ start: data.lenght, count: 20 });
  }
}
```

PS:
А планое появление контента можно будет сделать на CSS:

```
<div onScroll={event => onScrollList(event)} style={{ transition: ease 0.5s }}>
  {props.children}
</div>
```